# How to create the numeral two in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to create the numeral two using tikz. The below code is close, though there is a strange gap in the bottom left corner.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
    
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\draw [white] (0,-0.5) -- (0,0.5) -- (0.6,0.5); 
\draw[ultra thick]    (0,0.25) to[out=45,in=45,looseness=2.5]  (0,-0.45);   
\draw[ultra thick](0,-0.45) -- (0.5,-0.45);    
\path (0.7,0); 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Any advice on how to get it looking more like this:

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting both of your `draw[ultra thick]` lines into one single statement produces something more like what you are after:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [white] (0,-0.5) -- (0,0.5) -- (0.6,0.5);
\draw[ultra thick]    (0,0.25) to[out=45,in=45,looseness=2.5]  (0,-0.45) -- (0.5,-0.45);
\path (0.7,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It has a fairly sharp corner at the base, though, which may not be quite what you want.

The reason yours looks like it has a gap is because of the ends of the paths you are drawing. I might be slightly wrong in details, but the principle is essentially correct, here. The path ends with a square (the pen-type, essentially) centred on the co-ordinates provided, and rotated to the direction of travel. The two square ends are not rotated to the same direction, so the overlaps are not perfect, and leave the gap you are seeing.

With the version I provided, it's one path (not two, which it is in yours), and so the end doesn't have that 'overlap with gap'. There may be settings within tikz to change the ends, which you can play with to get something more to your liking. You may also be able to change the 'pen type' to be something other than square (a circle would work quite well). This can be done with `draw[line cap=round]`, so:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
    
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\draw [white] (0,-0.5) -- (0,0.5) -- (0.6,0.5); 
\draw[ultra thick, line cap=round]    (0,0.25) to[out=45,in=45,looseness=2.5]  (0,-0.45);   
\draw[ultra thick, line cap=round](0,-0.45) -- (0.5,-0.45);    
\path (0.7,0); 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

is likely to produce something more like what you are after.

Comment: That's fantastic! Thank you